# Sanctuaries at Beis El and Dan

Tags: mishkan-tabernacle, northern-kingdom, book-of-chronicles

There is no indication that the Northern Tribes created anything other than a tent "mishkan" in Dan and Beis El, or that even the Samaritans built anything other than a mishkan at Gerizim as there was in Shilo, Nov and Givon.
However in 2 Chronicles 13 verse 19 it says that Aviyah captured Beis El. Was the place of the sanctuary of Jeroboam, and they had control of it until the exile, or is it a different Beis El? I don't find anything about this in the meforshim (yet).
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Bible reports that in his wars against Jeroboam, Abijam succeeded in capturing the city of Beth El from the Kingdom of Israel, but Abijam himself died in a plague (II Chon. 13:19). One of the reasons traditionally given for Abijam’s early death is that he did not put a stop to the idolatrous cult at Beth El when the city came under his control (see JT *Yevamos* 16:3, *Midrash Shmuel* (§18), and *Bereishis Rabbah* (§65:20), cited by Malbim (to II Chron. 13:19).

Even though Abijam, king of Judah, captured Beth El from Jeroboam, it seems that through most of the period of Kings, Beth El belonged to the Kingdom of Israel, not to Judah. Indeed, the prophecies of Hosea and Amos castigate the Kingdom of Israel for their idolatrous site at Beth El, not the Kingdom of Judah. This would imply that even though Abjiam captured Beth El from the Kingdom of Israel, Israel later regained that city. However, Israel's recapturing Beth El is not mentioned explicitly in the Bible.

R. Shaul Goldman argues that the Bible's account of Abijam's death implies that his death brought about a temporary cessation in the fighting between Judah and Israel, with Israel gaining the upper hand. Given this understanding, he suggests that upon Abijam's death, the Kingdom of Judah lost the city of Beth El to the Kingdom of Israel. Similarly, R. Shamai Ostreicher argues that when the Bible attests to continuous wars between Judah and Israel in the respective reigns of Asa and Baasa (I Kgs. 15:16; 15:32), this means that the city of Beth El changed hands then and returned to the Kingdom of Israel.

In fact, rabbinic tradition about Abijam implies that Beth El returned to the Kingdom of Israel during or before Asa's reign. As mentioned above, tradition explains that Abijam was smitten with a plague as retribution for his failure to destroy the Golden Calf at Beth El, which continued tp survive for many generations until the fall of the Kingdom of Israel. If the city of Beth El remained in Judah's hands for longer than Abijam's reign, then Abijam's successor Asa should also have been criticized for allowing the Golden Calf to remain. The absence of such criticism against Asa in rabbinic literature thus implies that by the time he ascended the throne (or at least very early into his reign), the city of Beth El was no longer under his control and he could not be held responsible for the idolatry of the Kingdom of Israel.
R. Matisyahu Strashun (1817–1885) writes in *Matas Yah* (to *Bereishis Rabbah* §65:5) that even when Beth El was under Judah's control, the deviant practices performed there were always sponsored by the Kingdom of Israel.

Answer (score -2):

Apparently what happened was NOT a capture but only a siege of Beth El. In fact the king Aviya was punished for several reasons through early death, with on e of the reasons being that he besieged Beth El by did not destroy the egels, which I assume also means the altars used to sacrifice there.

Comment: Do you have a source for this answer?